How is wpf data transformation triggered at runtime
XML
  <ListBox x:Name="myData"  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Background="{StaticResource TransparentColor}" Grid.Row="1"
      BorderBrush="{StaticResource LeftGridColor}"  >
      <ListBox.Resources>
          <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dto:DownLoadDto}">
              <Grid >
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                      <TextBlock x:Name="id" Text="{Binding index}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                      <WrapPanel Margin="10,0,0,0">
                          <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width="40"/>
                          <StackPanel Margin="10,0,0,0">
                              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Des}" />
                          </StackPanel>
                      </WrapPanel>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Album}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                      <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding DataContext.ChnageLoveItemCommand,Source={x:Reference Name=win}}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=id ,Path=Text}">
                          <Path Data="M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100 Z " Fill="{Binding IsLove, Mode=OneWay ,Converter={StaticResource bursh}}"  Stroke="Red"  Stretch="Fill"   Width="16" Height="16" />
                      </Button>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid Grid.Column="4">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Size}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                  </Grid>
              </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.Resources>
  </ListBox>

Converter
    public class BoolToBurshConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool isLove = (bool)value;
            BrushConverter conv = new BrushConverter();
       
            if (isLove)
                return  conv.ConvertFromInvariantString("#FF0000") as System.Windows.Media.Brush;
            else
                return conv.ConvertFromInvariantString("#F5F5F7") as System.Windows.Media.Brush;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

Command
  [RelayCommand]
  private void ChnageLoveItem(string index)
  {
      var dto = data.FirstOrDefault(p => p.index == int.Parse(index));
      if (dto != null)
      {
          dto.IsLove = !dto.IsLove;
      }
  }

  <Path Data="M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100 Z " Fill="{Binding IsLove, Mode=OneWay ,Converter={StaticResource bursh}}"  Stroke="Red"  Stretch="Fill"   Width="16" Height="16" />

I am using data transformation on this path
When isLove is true, it converts to red and when islove is false, it converts to transparent, which is correct when the program is initialized. But when I try to change the value of isLove by command trigger while the program is running, the data conversion will not be called
I was hoping that if I triggered the command and changed the IsLove value while the program was running, I would be able to call the data transformation, but I had no idea and it made me very frustrated
The effect of the program when it runs
enter image description here
I don't have a good way

I would bind the Background to a view model property returning a Brush and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

That's one way, but I want to use this example to learn about converter
